# How to embed a div within a page, or how to strip all other divs

Tags: jquery, html, moodle

I'm attempting to embed a Moodle activity in a "section" and keep all links within that section.

This is on the same site and domain.

The activities have a url similar to:
https://example.edu.au/mod/assign/view.php?id=16764

I've successfully embedded the page with a div content replacement script I found here (https://css-tricks.com/ajax-load-container-contents/).

```
<div id="area" style="overflow: hidden;"></div>
<script>
    $("#area").load("https://example.edu.au/mod/assign/view.php?id=16764 #page-content");
</script>
```

The problem is that I need any links like "add submission", to keep the content in the div on the parent page.
With the above code, they follow any links and load the contents fullscreen.

I've tried using iFrames and code to remove extra divs, but everything I've tried to use that I've found online just loads the entire page, header and all.

I'm happy with any solution, but my code skill is at "edit variables and hope for the best" level.

Comment: may I ask what is your goal/what is the problem you are trying to solve? Also, the activities you are trying to fetch are within the same domain, Moodle and course?

Comment: I'm trying to get a course design for short (less than 10 activities) courses.   <br> 
I'm using the "buttons" course format to get a nice view, and I've got each button displaying an activity.    <br>
  <br>
Yes, all things I'm trying to fetch are in the same domain, Moodle instance and course.